# Is babel required if target browsers are Chrome and Firefox only?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

The below code contains next features of modern JavaScript:

- **async/await** keywords
- **Promise**
- **Symbol**
- New methods of **Object** that does not supported in Internet Explorer

---

```
loadModule();

async function loadModule() {
  const MODULE = await import('./TestModules/testJsModule.js');
  console.log(MODULE.b);
}

let promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

promise1.then(()=> {
  console.log('done');
});

console.log(promise1);

let obj = {};

obj[Symbol("a")] = "a";

let obj1 = {};
let a = Symbol('a');
let b = Symbol.for('b');

obj1[a] = 'localSymbol';
obj1[b] = 'globalSymbol';

let objectSymbols = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj1);
```

If to build this code by **webpack** *without* **babel**, it will work in **Chrome**, **Firefox** and even **Edge**. So, is my conclusion correct that currently we don't need **babel** if target browsers are Chrome of Firefox?

Comment: that seems obvious

Comment: As long as their browsers are up to date that is. If for some reason your targets are stuck on an older version of their browsers (because they need old plugins or similar) then you'd still need to use babel.

Comment: @MinusFour, Thank you for the comment. What you said is actual only for the cases when user disabled default auto updating in Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: @Jaromanda X, not for non-highclass professionals.

Comment: I said "seems" not "is" :p

Comment: @GurebuBokofu Yes, that would be one reason. I don't know what's your use case exactly but say you are doing this for a specific audience and they are stuck on an older version of their browser for compatibility reasons then you want to make sure that version is capable of all these features.